# Checking for value in list of rows per user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working with a list of survey data:

| UserID | User Name | SurveyID | QuestionID | ResponseID | isSkipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 100 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | Test1 | 100 | 20 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Test2 | 101 | 10 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | Test2 | 101 | 20 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 102 | 10 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 102 | 20 | 6 | 1 |

I'm looking for a query to give me the user, the SurveyID, and a flag (0 = Complete/1 = Not Complete) telling me if they completed all the questions (all the isSkipped values are 0)... so the end should be....

| UserID | User Name | SurveyID | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | Test2 | 101 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 102 | 1 |

Can anyone help me out? I've tried using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`/`COUNT` and such, but I'm always getting more than one row per user.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, for your required result, you require:

```
select UserId, User_Name, SurveyId, 
  case when sum(isSkipped) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as Complete
from t
group by UserId, User_Name, SurveyId;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked like a charm.  I must be having a brain for not using the when > 0 part.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's enough they completed one question to be considered complete then you can just choose `max(isSkipped)` for your `complete` status.

```
select   UserID
        ,[User Name]
        ,SurveyID
        ,max(isSkipped) as Complete
from     t
group by UserID, [User Name], SurveyID
```

| UserID | User Name | SurveyID | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | Test2 | 101 | 1 |
| 3 | Test3 | 102 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ks2v4gei)